# Failed to execute 'animate' on 'element': parameter 1 is not of type 'object'

Tags: javascript

```
this.animate = 
 function(name,color){

this.style.transform = name;

this.style.backgroundColor= color;

};

document.body.animate("translateY('120px')",'red');
```

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example of you problem, then it would be easier to help.

Comment: don't pass `translateY('120px')` it as an string, remove string quotes.

Comment: `document.body.animate(translateY('120px'), 'red')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a minimum you need an animation object and a duration for the animation [Element.animate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate). And then I think you got some of your code upside down.

```js
const animate = function(element, animationObj, colorStr) {
  element.animate(animationObj, {
    duration: 2000
  });
  element.style.backgroundColor = colorStr;
};

let testElm = document.getElementById("test");

animate(testElm, {
  transform: 'translateY(120px)'
}, 'red');
```

```html
<div id="test">test<div>
```